# MVC @HTML.ActionLink

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm starting to work with my first MVC project in VS2013, having never used MVC before.

I have a site with a few pages on that I'm happy with.

On one of the pages I have added (through a tutorial) the following command:

```
@Html.ActionLink("List of Items", "Index", "Items")
```

And this provides me with a link on my page with the text "List of Items", and clicking on this link does in fact give me the list of the items pulled from the database.

However, I actually want the list of the items to appear on this page automatically without having to click onto the link first, but I'll be honest I've no idea how to do this.

I'm happy to go and look and read and learn, but I'm not really sure where to go or what I'd be looking for at this early stage.

Comment: You just have to move the code of Controller-action Items/Index to the corresponding Action of your page Controller. If you paste your corresponding cotrollers we could help you better

Comment: Hi Thank you for this. The code in my Items Controller is: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.SItems.ToList());
        }. Is this the code I'd need to place elsewhere? If so, where would I need to place this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the Get method of the page where you have defined **@Html.ActionLink("List of Items", "Index", "Items")**, directly call the **Index** Action method of the **Items** Controller if you are coming to this page from some other page else if you are loading this page directly via Url then directly type this Url i.e. **/Items/Index** in the browser.

If you are accessing the Index method directly, make sure it is a Get method.